# What's a better way of generating two maps using a Sequence of Strings (as keys)?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

My goal is to create two maps with keys all from a Seq[String].

For example, given:

```
val keys = Seq("key1", "key2")
```

I would like to get:

```
val map1 = Map("key1" -> List("something I get using key1"), "key2" -> List("something I get using key2"))
val map2 = Map("key1" -> List("some other stuff I get using key1"), "key2" -> List("some other stuff I get using key2"))
```

I've got a solution as below, but, given how cluttered and long this solution is, I feel like there must be a better/cleaner/more Scala-like approach.

Is there something I can do better in my solution?  Appreciate the help in advanced!

```
val test = Seq("a", "b")

val (map1, map2) = 
(for (key <- test) yield {
      ((key -> List("some stuff with key")), (key -> List("some other stuff with key")))
    }).unzip match {
      case (seq1: Seq[(String, List[String])], seq2: Seq[(String, List[String])]) => {
        (seq1.toMap, seq2.toMap)
      }
      case _ => (Map(), Map())
    }
```

EDIT: Dima's solution below is definitely what I will go with since it's much simpler/easier to read, but my question here is more of is there a Scala way to avoid running .map twice on the same set of seq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `unzip` on a single call to `map` as follow, delivers two collections of tuples that can be treated as `Map`,

```
val (map1, map2) = keys.map ( k => (k -> op1(k), k -> op2(k)) ).unzip
```

Namely, `map1.toMap` and `map2.toMap` converts each collection of tuples to `Map`. This involves though the need for two *iterations* over `keys`, one from `map`, the other from `unzip`.

Comment: Since keys is a Seq, map1 and map2 end up being Seq[(String, X]], so I'll have to call map1.toMap and map2.toMap individually, right?

Comment: @DKT imho yes, unless you use mutable maps that are constructed incrementally.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
val keys = Seq("key1", "key2")
val map1 = keys
   .map { k => k -> doThingsWith(k) }
val ma2 = keyes 
   .map { k => k -> doOtherThingsWith(k) }
```

Comment: Ya, this is definitely what I will end up using in the end if no better answers came up.  I was just curious if Scala/FP offered a way to do this in one line (vs running .map twice on the same seq).

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't do this in one line.  This solution is the clearest.